# VUEJS - How to use data variable from child component into parent

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-props

I'm trying to refactor my code into couple component, so that it looks more readable and cleaner, but I got confused how to use data variable child component in parent. In the ModalIdentifier the `addPI_ID` it's supposed to set into `false` so that we click `ADD` button the modal identifier will set into true and modal will pop up

ModalIdentifier.vue (child)

```
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="addPI_ID" width="600">
  </v-dialog>
</template>

export default {
   props: ["addPI_ID"],
}
```

addUser.vue(parent)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <modal-identifier :addPI_ID="false"></modal-identifier>

    //there's button, if we click that modal identifier dialog will pops up
    <v-btn
        color="#8FC23E"
        class="mt-3 mb-6"
        @click="addPI_ID = true"
    >ADD</v-btn>
  </div>
</template>
```

this part I got confused, what's the better idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props are for parent -> child 
You can use $emit for child -> parent

in parent:

- Use **addPI_ID** to control the dialog(show/hide), passing the value through **props** from parent to child
- Listen the event "**update**" to be **emitted** from child to parent with the new value of **addPI_ID**
- Changing the value of **addPI_ID** to true (show dialog) when the button ADD is clicked

```vue
<modal-identifier :addPI_ID="addPI_ID" v-on:update="addPI_ID = $event"></modal-identifier>
<v-btn color="#8FC23E" class="mt-3 mb-6" @click="addPI_ID = true">ADD</v-btn>
```

in child:

- Create a computed property "**show**", to **emit** our custom event "**update**" to parent(with the new value of **addPI_ID**), whenever we set the value of "**show**". And when we read the value of "**show**"(get) it returns the current value of our prop **addPI_ID**
- Prop **addPI_ID** receive the value from parent

```vue
<template>
  <div>
    <v-dialog v-model="show" width="600">
      <v-btn color="primary" @click="show = false">Close</v-btn>
    </v-dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
     addPI_ID: Boolean
  },
  computed: {
    show: {
      get() {
        return this.addPI_ID;
      },
      set(addPI_ID) {
        this.$emit('update', addPI_ID);
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

hope it helps! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I think you shouldn't be passing "false" into modal-identifier element in the parent. You should pass in the actual value of addPI_ID, like this:

```
<modal-identifier :addPI_ID="addPI_ID"></modal-identifier>
```

You should also declare a variable addPI_ID in the parent if you haven't already:

```
  data: {
    ...
    addPI_ID: false,
  },
```